# Converting audio files from .wav to mp3 using GNU Parallel

Tags: python, audio, bitrate, lossy-compression

I am trying to convert a full folder of audio files(.wav) to .mp3 by changing the bitrate. The problem is each audio file name consist of multiple '.' and ends with .wav. I am using gnu-parallel to convert the audio signals bitrate and save them as .mp3. My command line:

```
ls wavs | cut -d '.' -f 1 | parallel -I% ffmpeg -i wavs/%.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 wavs_2/%.mp3
```

but i am getting error due to multiple '.' in my audio file name. Since 'cut' will only accept one delimeter, it just giving **"No such file or directory"** error. How do I solve this? Here is the example of my audio files: wav_1.wav_norm_mono.wav.

NB: Each directory of the audio files contains more than 1000 audio files.

Answer (score 0):

I know 3 month ...

Replace "wavs/%.wav" by {}
and
Replace "wavs_2/%.mp3" by {}.finalname.mp3

A complete line working for me:

```
parallel -a "/dev/shm/findaudio.txt" ffmpeg -i {} -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k {}.320k.mp3
```

I search files before and put in findaudio.txt

Full batch here:
https://github.com/LostByteSoft/ConvertAACtoAC3

Take the file "Convert ALL folder MP3 320 (parallel).sh"

Another solution is to transcode all files in a specified directory:

```
parallel -j 4 ffmpeg -i {} -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k {.}.320k.mp3 ::: "/home/USER/Music"/*.*
```

Only for linux..

See ya